# Saving Cypress output to pdf file or similar

Tags: cypress

Is there a way to save the output shown in the linked [video](http://cypress.io) (on the left side) to a pdf file or similar? I have started experimenting with other Reporters offered, but the format of them does not seem to be as clear for reporting. Suggestions for Reporters that could do something similar as opposed to only XML would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this yet, but it's on my to-do list.  It promises to do just that, store the command log output to a json file.  It's written by Gleb, one of the cypress people, so it should integrate and work well with cypress.

https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-failed-log

Answer (score 0):

You may export a screenshot with both, the left sidebar and the application preview by using the `screenshot` function with `capture: runner`:

```
cy.visit(`http://www.fabiobiondi.dev`);
cy.viewport('iphone-6' )
cy.screenshot('imageName', { capture: 'runner'})
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqN0E.png

Comment: Seems limiting if the test has more than a few lines.